# Post-Запрос без ответа

Tags: python, http, post, get

Как в python послать post/get запрос, не тратя при этом трафик на получение ответа от сервера?

Comment: не могли бы вы уточнить вопрос? нужно блокировать ответ сервера? сервер ваш?

Comment: блокировать ответ? Нет, но тогда трафик на получение ответа всё равно будет тратиться, если я правильно вас понял. Сервер не мой

Comment: вы хотите сэкономить трафик чужого сервера? ))